# install caffe on mac " Error: invalid option: --with-python"

Tags: python, caffe, protobuf-c

when I install the caffe on mac according to :

Remaining dependencies, with / without Python

```
# with Python pycaffe needs dependencies built from source

brew install --build-from-source --with-python -vd protobuf
brew install --build-from-source -vd boost boost-python
# without Python the usual installation suffices
brew install protobuf boost
```

I paste the second one to the terminal, and result is:

```
Error: invalid option: --with-python
```

I can not find any similar problem, can some help me with that?

Comment: maybe?
"Homebrew/homebrew-core formulae no longer have install options."
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/5732

Answer (score 4):

Options have been removed from Homebrew core formulas and only exist in taps now. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510). Building with python has been made the default behavior for `protobuf`.

See the [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/79b2f6c901d1ba491f5604f83db5e05fff80f765/Formula/protobuf.rb#L49-L51), lines 49-51.

> ```ruby
> chdir "python" do
>   system "python3", *Language::Python.setup_install_args(libexec),
>                     "--cpp_implementation"
> ```

So it should be fine to run

```
brew install --build-from-source -vd protobuf
```